# C# how to add a DLL to the release build (SimConnect.dll)?

Tags: c#, dll, release

So I have this Windows forms project where I'm using the SimConnect.dll.

I referenced the Microsoft.FlightSimulator.SimConnect.dll to my project (it's inside my project's folder).

The project runs fine when selecting Debug x64

[image: debug]

But now I'm trying to run my project as release so I can publish or create a setup for it.

But every time I change to release x64 I get `System.BadImageFormatException`
[image: release]
[image: badImageFormation]

Basically, my question is: How can I export my project so I can publish it with a DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like the System.BadImageFormatException is related to differences between x86 and x64 platforms. All I had to do is change the release environment from AnyCPU to x64